# Windows File Search doesn't work on TrueCrypt protected volumes

Tags: windows-8, encryption, truecrypt, windows-search

I have found a problem with Windows Search and my TrueCrypt volumes.

My laptop is encrypted with BitLocker for system partition, and TrueCrypt 7.1a for the rest of hard drives, in order to share some partitions with Linux too.

I have a batch startup script that automatically mounts all my drivs into TrueCrypt providing encryption password

```
@echo off
set password=__________
set truecrypt_bin="C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"

%truecrypt_bin% /v \Device\Harddisk1\Partition6 /l M /p %password% /q

%truecrypt_bin% /v \Device\Harddisk0\Partition4 /l H /p %password% /q

%truecrypt_bin% /v \Device\Harddisk1\Partition7 /l O /p %password% /q

@echo on
```

Given that this is not the best idea to perform startup actions (since Windows 8 hibernates kernel session I always get "drive already mounted" error except when I update the system), it works just fine to allow me to manage my drives.

The problem is with Windows Search. I have a drive full with music that I can't basically search. Whatever I put in a search box when I'm inside a directory results in **no results**. Whatever. Even if the file is under my eyes.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it was a really dumb problem. After trying and retrying with the index options I had to:

- Manually add the encrypted volume to the index
- Rebuild the index from scratch
- Wait a couple of hours

Now it looks like it finds files

Answer (score 0):

if you do a manual mount of the TC volume after boot you need to restart the Windows Service "Windows Search" (WSearch) and then you should see the drive in the search indexing option of windows.